Dynamic selection of columns that are to be displayed in a matrix in Power BI Dashboard
I would like to create a dashboard where the users of the dashboard can select the dimension columns and fact columns that they want to see the values for, and these should appear on the dashboard as a matrix to be able to view the values for the chosen columns.
The dimension and fact columns list will be displayed as two separate multi-select slicers.
When a user accesses this dashboard, they can choose the specific columns(dimensions and facts) that they want to see the values for.
The data model is a simple star schema, with 1 fact table and 6 dimension tables.
Please help me in designing this dashboard.
